# Disable new WP3.5 Media Picker

Tags: uploads

I've got a compatibility issue with the new media picker in WP 3.5 and a plugin I have to use. Until the plugin is updated with a patch, I'd like to simply disable the new media picker, and fall back to the old-school one that was before WP 3.5. Is this possible setting a constant, or using a filter somehow?

Comment: I'd like to see the answer but I very much doubt this is possible.

Comment: Have you read [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81806/wordpress-3-5-switch-back-to-old-media-uploader)?